# Определение обоев на iOS

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Доброго времени суток. Во встроенных iOS-приложениях есть много примеров использования полупрозрачных елементов, под которыми видны установленные обои. Я думал, что это возможно только в приложениях системы, но заблюренные обои есть и в приложениях из App Store. Подскажите, как это делается? Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так:

```
       @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *bgImageView;

 -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.bgImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    UIToolbar* bgToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:screenRect];
    bgToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
    [self.bgImageView insertSubview:bgToolbar belowSubview:self.bgImageView];
}
```

Вот тут еще побольше http://goo.gl/9bVNNj.

Comment: Нет, не то( Заблюренная картинка в таком случае выбирается мной, а мне нужно, чтобы использовались обои с домашнего экрана.